# Erro "TS1005: ';' expected" ao compilar classe com TypeScript

Tags: classes, sintaxe, typescript

Estou estudando classes do TypeScript através da documentação oficial: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. Utilizei exatamente o mesmo código de exemplo da documentação:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Porém, ao tentar executar o comando `tsc greeter.ts` para compilar o código acima, estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> \greeter.ts(13,5): error TS1005: ';' expected.

O que está errado?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema (não estou conseguindo colar o URL do código para ver). Coloque aqui e veja: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: Aqui funcionou corretamente, tenta reinstalar o `node-typescript`. Da uma olhada pra ver se tu tá pegando o arquivo certo também, pois o código que você colocou só tem 11 linhas e ele tá dando erro na linha 13.

Comment: Ao rodar o comando tsc -v, estou obtendo o seguinte resultado: Version 1.0.3.0. Já rodei npm update typescript e npm install -g typescript@latest, porém, a versão não atualiza. Estou fazendo esse teste em um computador com Windows 7, pode ter alguma relação?

Answer (score 2):

O problema estava ocorrendo por estar utilizando a versão **1.0.3.0** do TypeScript. Para solucionar o problema, precisei desinstalar o pacote que estava sendo utilizado (`npm uninstall -g typescript`) e instalar a versão mais recente: `npm install -g typescript@latest`.

Mesmo depois de atualizar a versão do typescript via npm, o comando `tsc -v` ainda retornava o valor:

> Version 1.0.3.0

.

Fui conferir o caminho do `tsc` configurado no meu PATH e vi que estava apontando para um arquivo diferente do instalado pelo npm: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\`

Atualizei o caminho do tsc no PATH para o local de instalação do pacote npm: `C:\Users\marcell.alves\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin` e o código foi compilado corretamente.

Detalhe importante: estou utilizando Windows 7. Não sei se o mesmo problema se aplica para outros sistemas operacionais.